# aws api body mapping template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api-design, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to format the output from my aws api but can't get one of the lists in the object to come through. I have the data loaded in dynamodb and my data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "lastname": "person1",
    "firstname": "last2",
    "employeeid": 7,
    "hrs": [
      {
        "availhrs": "16",
        "ttlhrs": "12",
        "bllhrs": "14",
        "rto": "16",
        "ondeckhrs": "0",
        "nonbllhrs": "0",
        "employeeid": 78,
        "dtmonth": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "clientid": 1,
        "clientId": 1,
        "employeeId": 78
      },
      {
        "availhrs": "16",
        "ttlhrs": "17",
        "bllhrs": "15",
        "rto": "26.5",
        "ondeckhrs": "0",
        "nonbllhrs": "0",
        "employeeid": 78,
        "dtmonth": "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "clientid": 1,
        "clientId": 1,
        "employeeId": 78
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I try to format it like this:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{ 
    "employees": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) 
        {
            "employeeid": "$elem.employeeid.N",
            "lastname": "$elem.lastname.S",
            "firstname": "$elem.firstname.S",
            "hrs": [
                #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items.hrs)
                {
                            "availhrs": "$elem.availhrs",
                            "ttlhrs": "$elem.ttlhrs",
                            "bllhrs": "$elem.bllhrs",
                            "rto": "$elem.rto",
                            "ondeckhrs": "$elem.ondeckhrs",
                            "nonbllhrs": "$elem.nonbllhrs",
                            "dtmonth": "$elem.dtmonth"
                }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                #end
            ]
        }#if($foreach.hasNext).#end
        #end
    ]
}
```

but then my output looks like this:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "employeeid": "7",
      "lastname": "last2",
      "firstname": "person1",
      "hrs": []
    }
  ]
}
```

what am I doing wrong in the formating where my hrs part is not coming out?

Comment: Can you post your model here?

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop is not correct. You should do the iteration over $elem.hrs instead of $inputRoot.Item.hrs

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{ 
    "employees": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) 
        {
            "employeeid": "$elem.employeeid.N",
            "lastname": "$elem.lastname.S",
            "firstname": "$elem.firstname.S",
            "hrs": [
                #foreach($hour in $elem.hrs)
                {
                            "availhrs": "$hour.availhrs",
                            "ttlhrs": "$hour.ttlhrs",
                            "bllhrs": "$hour.bllhrs",
                            "rto": "$hour.rto",
                            "ondeckhrs": "$hour.ondeckhrs",
                            "nonbllhrs": "$hour.nonbllhrs",
                            "dtmonth": "$hour.dtmonth"
                }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                #end
            ]
        }#if($foreach.hasNext).#end
        #end
    ]
}
```

Comment: so I get the `hrs` object back but all of the detail is blank...like this: `{
  "employees": [
    {
      "employeeid": "78",
      "lastname": "last2",
      "firstname": "person1",
      "hrs": [
        {
          "availhrs": "",
          "ttlhrs": "",
          "bllhrs": "",
          "rto": "",
          "ondeckhrs": "",
          "nonbllhrs": "",
          "dtmonth": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: OK, in that case you need to add .S or .N, for example $hour.availhrs.S (or .N) for numbers, like you did with employeeid and lastname

Comment: ok...so tried that but still no luck....I changed `$elem.hrs` to `$elem.hrs.L` and got the correct number of objects back in hrs but still the stuff in hrs is blank?

Comment: Log the output of the dynamodb query, so you can exactly see the input of the template.

Comment: Try changing the inner foreach to iterate over $elem.hrs.Items: #foreach($hour in $elem.hrs.Items)